# Tutorial on Using OpenSSL with pthreads

Tags: reference, pthreads, openssl

[OpenSSL documents](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html) state that it can safely be used in multi-threaded applications provided that at least two callback functions are set, locking_function and threadid_func....

I've written programs which use OpenSSL API. Moreover, I know how to use pthreads. However, the OpenSSL documents are written in the form of a manual, and I can't see a step-by-step guide on what I have to do when using OpenSSL in a multi-threaded app.

Is there a tutorial on using OpenSSL with pthreads? (I searched the web, but no satisfactory result appeared.)

**PS:** I'm working in Debian Lenny & Ubuntu Lucid/Maverick.

**PS2:** OpenSSL includes a sample, but it's far too complicated to start with.

Comment: I did a search on the web and found this code below - unfortunately I do not know openSSL enough to tell you it will help, but it seems related to what you asking :)
<p>
http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs772/sourcecode/NSwO/compiled/common.c
<p>
good luck

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chapter 10 of the book [The Definitive Guide to Linux Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593227) includes a section **Thread-safe Programming with OpenSSL** (on pages 255-259). This section details how OpenSSL and the pthreads library work. Specially, it tells how to setup the callback functions both in static allocation (where the number of threads are known *a priori*) and dynamic allocation (where threads are created and destroyed *on the fly*).

Another good source is Section 4.1 of the book [Network Security with OpenSSL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600270X), titled **Multithread Support**. It provides static/dynamic allocation mechanisms in subsections 4.1.1 and 4.1.2, respectively.

Finally, there's the book [Unix-Netzwerkprogrammierung mit Threads, Sockets und SSL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540002995), which is by far the most comprehensive one on the subject. Unfortunately, the English translation of this German book is not available.

**Edit:** The above references are now considered obsolete, as OpenSSL 1.1.0 [changelog](https://www.openssl.org/news/cl110.txt) explains:

> OpenSSL now uses a new threading API. **It is no longer necessary to set locking callbacks to use OpenSSL in a multi-threaded environment.** There are two supported threading models: pthreads and windows threads. It is also possible to configure OpenSSL at compile time for "no-threads". The old threading API should no longer be used. The functions have been replaced with "no-op" compatibility macros.
>
> [Alessandro Ghedini, Matt Caswell]

This is further elaborated in OpenSSL blog post [OpenSSL and Threads](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/02/21/threads/).

See also [this issue on OpenSSL GitHub repository](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2165), which is open since 2017.

Answer (score 11):

Don't know about a tutorial, but here are two libcurl-based examples that might help:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/opensslthreadlock.html
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threaded-ssl.html

Comment: Thank you +1. I have elaborated my answer based on yours :)

Comment: why not just add a function init/clean in openssl or libcurl api for multithreading ??

Answer (score 9):

- openssl must be configured with threads option `./config thread -D_REENTRANT`
- It's a matter of copy & paste; the openssl tar ball includes a sample in file `crypto/threads/mttest.c`

copy relevant platform specific implementation & call thread_setup for initialization and thread_cleanup for wrap up;

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best answer, IMHO. All other answers reference dated methods. For me, I checked with OpenSSL version I was running with `openssl version -a`. Then, I referenced the exact version with the git tag, which in my case, was `https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_1/crypto/threads/mttest.c`. When checking the OpenSSL version with this method, you can see if its compiled with `-D_REENTRANT` as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Wodin's answer using cURL references, all I did was copy these 4 functions

```
#include <openssl/crypto.h> //In addition to other ssl headers
```

...

```
/* we have this global to let the callback get easy access to it */ 
static pthread_mutex_t *lockarray;

static void lock_callback(int mode, int type, char *file, int line)
{
  (void)file;
  (void)line;
  if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(lockarray[type]));
  }
  else {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(lockarray[type]));
  }
}

static unsigned long thread_id(void)
{
  unsigned long ret;

  ret=(unsigned long)pthread_self();
  return(ret);
}

static void init_locks(void)
{
  int i;

  lockarray=(pthread_mutex_t *)OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() *
                                        sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
  for (i=0; i<CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&(lockarray[i]),NULL);
  }

  CRYPTO_set_id_callback((unsigned long (*)())thread_id);
  CRYPTO_set_locking_callback((void (*)(int, int, const char*, int))lock_callback);
}

static void kill_locks(void)
{
  int i;

  CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(NULL);
  for (i=0; i<CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++)
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&(lockarray[i]));

  OPENSSL_free(lockarray);
}
```

Then call these two functions as follows

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   //pthread initialization goes here

  init_locks();

  //pthread stuff here (create, join, etc)


  kill_locks();
  return 0;
}
```

That got rid of all weird errors with `SSL_load_error_strings();` segfaults and double free condition from glibc.

Comment: Great example! Can we use reader-writer locks instead of mutex in "lock_callback"? Does OpenSSL support that?

Comment: @manpatha - Yes, the call backs send a CRYPTO_WRITE or CRYPTO_READ to the lock function, so in theory, you can use that to determine what kind of lock you need.