# Multithreading in openssl s_client

Tags: c, multithreading, ssl, openssl, segmentation-fault

I want to enable multithreading in `openssl s_client`. Basically, I want to run, say 5 different handshakes on 5 different threads when i run the `s_client` program.

Currently, this is how I'm going about it.

`$ apps/openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -multithread`

So, I take in a `switch` called `-multithread` and set it to true in `apps/s_client.c` if multithreading needs to be enabled.

Now, the request and handshake is taken care of in lines `1005` to `1923` in [this program](http://osxr.org/openssl/source/apps/s_client.c#1005). So, I create an inner function from `1005` to `1923`, and try running that function in a different thread.

That is,

```
int function_handshake()
{
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ....
    ....
    apps_shutdown();
    OPENSSL_EXIT(ret);
}
```

This is a function inside a function(the parent function being `main`)
After this function, I run this `for` loop to create a certain `number_of_threads`.

```
  for(current_thread_count=0; current_thread_count < number_of_threads; current_thread_count++)
     {
           init_locks();
           thread_error = pthread_create(&(tid[current_thread_count]), NULL, function_handshake, NULL);
           if(thread_error!=0)
           {
                printf("Can't create thread, [%s]\n", strerror(thread_error));
                goto end;
           }
           printf("----------thread created------------\n\n");
           thread_error = pthread_join(tid[current_thread_count], NULL);
           if(thread_error!=0)
           {
                printf("Can't join thread, [%s]\n", strerror(thread_error));
                goto end;
           }
           kill_locks();
    }
```

The `init_locks()` and `kill_locks()` functions are got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27567259/2214576)

When I try running this program, it works fine in one iteration - The first handshake is successful. However, I run into `memory errors` and `segmentation faults` in the second handshake.

Please let me know what is wrong, or if there's any better / other way to do multithreading in the `openssl s_client`.

Comment: You must call `init_locks()` only once in your program, i.e. before launching your threads. Similarly, call `kill_locks()` only once (after you've joined if joinable threads) at termination.