# Multithreaded program using OpenSSL and locks randomly crashes

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, openssl

I have logic for signing soap documents which use OpenSSL methods like:

```
OpenSSL_add_all_digests, 
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
EVP_DigestUpdate
```

and so on. Of course every logic for signing document is running in different thread.

According to many topics about that subject I created static class for handling OpenSSL threads:

```
unsigned long SomeStaticClass::pthreads_thread_id(){
        unsigned long ret;

        ret = ( unsigned long )pthread_self();
        return ret;
}

void SomeStaticClass::pthreads_locking_callback( int mode, int type, const char* /*file*/, int /*line*/ ){

        if( mode & CRYPTO_LOCK ){
                printf("CRYPTO_LOCK_MODE type: %d\n", type);
                pthread_mutex_lock( &( lock_cs[type] ) );
        }
        else{
                printf("UNLOCK type: %d\n", type);
                pthread_mutex_unlock( &( lock_cs[type] ) );
        }
}

void SomeStaticClass::thread_setup(){

        printf("THREAD SETUP\n");
        lock_cs = ( pthread_mutex_t* )OPENSSL_malloc( CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof( pthread_mutex_t ) );
        for( int i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++ ){
                pthread_mutex_init( &( lock_cs[i] ), NULL );
        }

        CRYPTO_set_id_callback( SomeStaticClass::pthreads_thread_id );
        CRYPTO_set_locking_callback( SomeStaticClass::pthreads_locking_callback );
}

void SomeStaticClass::thread_cleanup(){

        printf("THREAD CLEANUP\n");
        CRYPTO_set_id_callback( NULL );
        CRYPTO_set_locking_callback( NULL );
        for( int i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++ ) {
                pthread_mutex_destroy( &( lock_cs[i] ) );
        }

        OPENSSL_free( lock_cs );
}
```

I left printf for debugging purpose. I know some of these methods are deprecated, but I can only use openssl 0.9.8.

I run thread_setup before runnig threads, and thread_cleanup after join them. Unfortunately my app still randomly crashes when I am using many threads. I get SIGSEGV just after pthreads_locking_callback was calling, cause I get on console `CRYPTO_LOCK_MODE type: 2`. According to backtrace it crashes after calling OpenSSL_add_all_digests or EVP_DigestUpdate.

So the question is why OpenSSL crashes since I am using proper methods for handling multi-threaded program. What I am missing?

**EDIT:**
It is not duplicate of [Tutorial on Using OpenSsl with pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919420/tutorial-on-using-openssl-with-pthreads) because as I mentioned I am already using this classic functions for multithread application.

**EDIT2:**
It works!
Looks like @Matt Caswell was right. Thank you for the correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tutorial on Using OpenSSL with pthreads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919420/tutorial-on-using-openssl-with-pthreads)

Comment: How do you know the problem is with OpenSSL and not with your own code?

Comment: @AndrewHenle it works perfect on one thread, it crashes when I am using multiple threads, and it always crashes on openssl functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of these functions:

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
```

Are library *initialisation* functions. You are expected to call them once prior to the calling of other OpenSSL functions. These are not thread safe. Call them before you setup your locking callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that one hour ago, and now I am testing it. so far, so good.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was not aware of the detail. Its now updated at [Library Initialization | Static Locks](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback is now deprecated, what should be used now?

Comment: From OpenSSL 1.1.0 and above there is no need to set locking callbacks at all, or call any of the above mentioned initialisation functions. It's all done automatically.