# How do I write thread-safe OpenSSL code the new way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openssl, thread-safety

I'm learning how to write a multi-threaded DTLS server using OpenSSL. I've been looking through documentation, and it looks like OpenSSL should work with multiple threads if i set `CRYPTO_set_id_callback` and `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback`. I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.1c, and when I look in `crypto.h`, I find this:

```
/*
 * The old locking functions have been removed completely without compatibility
 * macros. This is because the old functions either could not properly report
 * errors, or the returned error values were not clearly documented.
 * Replacing the locking functions with no-ops would cause race condition
 * issues in the affected applications. It is far better for them to fail at
 * compile time.
 * On the other hand, the locking callbacks are no longer used.  Consequently,
 * the callback management functions can be safely replaced with no-op macros.
 */
#  define CRYPTO_num_locks()            (1)
#  define CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(func)
#  define CRYPTO_get_locking_callback()         (NULL)
#  define CRYPTO_set_add_lock_callback(func)
#  define CRYPTO_get_add_lock_callback()        (NULL)
```

So, I looks like this method is outdated. What should I do instead to ensure that my OpenSSL code is thread safe?

--
After researching some more, I've found this: [Tutorial on Using OpenSSL with pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919420/tutorial-on-using-openssl-with-pthreads). I've also found https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback.html. 
However, `CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback()` is also a no-op! It looks like I could do nothing but compile OpenSSL with the right flags.

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean by that? I don't plan on re-writing parts of openssl... I'm only compiling the latest version with threads and zlib. What are some examples of these "professional implementations?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you no longer need to set up locks in OpenSSL 1.1.0 and later.

> Programming with OpenSSL
>   Is OpenSSL thread-safe?
>
> > Yes but with some limitations; for example, an SSL connection cannot be used concurrently > by multiple threads. This is true for most OpenSSL objects.
> >
> > For version 1.1.0 and later, there is nothing further you need do.
> >
> > For earlier versions than 1.1.0, it is necessary for your application to set up the thread callback functions. To do this, your application must call CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(3) and one of the CRYPTO_THREADID_set... API's. See the OpenSSL threads manpage for details and "note on multi-threading" in the INSTALL file in the source distribution.

You can check OpenSSL faq [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html)!

Comment: Yes. I just compiled OpenSSL with `./config --release threads` and moved on. :)

Comment: "For version 1.1.0 and later, there is nothing further you need do." Does this mean there are mutexes within openssl? Or, only if you compile it with mutexes?